# How to set an array contains value condition with Ruby Sequel?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sequel

I have this function that I need to modified to select from `elements` table the rows in which the column `filters`(array type) contain the `feature_id` param

```
def get_categories_by_company_and_feature(company_id:,feature_id:)
   DB[:categories]
  .where(company_id: company_id)
  .join(:elements, category_id: :id)
  .order(:category_name, :element_name)
  .select_all(:categories, :elements)
  .select_append(Sequel[:categories][:user_active].as(:category_user_active),
      Sequel[:categories][:id].as(:category_id),
      Sequel[:elements][:id].as(:element_id))
end
```

I've seen documentation with `array_op.contains(:a)` and many operators< but I don't know how to combine it with this syntax.

Also, what kind of operators can I apply for a column like  `Sequel[:categories][:user_active]`?

Comment: You can try asking on the google talk channel, the creator of Sequel is there all the time. https://groups.google.com/g/sequel-talk